Obtaining the time as linuxtime in an MSBuild .targets file
I'm trying to inject a numeric linux time value (i.e., seconds since the start of the Linux epoch) for when a build was made as a pre-processor definition in a C++ project. The below code works for BUILD_YEAR, but for BUILD_DATETIME I get an error suggesting Subtract either doesn't exist or is static, neither of which seems to be true. Is this the wrong approach? It seems to be valid C#, but I can't find any documentation for what language the targets files actually support.
I'm aware there are approaches for processing __TIME__ into a numeric value, but this seemed like it ought to be a more appropriate way to do it.

Invalid static method invocation syntax: ".Subtract([System.DateTime]::UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds". Method 'System.DateTime.Subtract' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(a, b)). Check that all parameters are defined, are of the correct type, and are specified in the right order.

<Project ToolsVersion="16.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>  
        <!-- All Builds -->
        <BUILD_YEAR>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy"))</BUILD_YEAR>
        <BUILD_DATETIME>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Subtract([System.DateTime]::UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds)</BUILD_DATETIME>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Note: This will ultimately come from the same path as Version.rc -->
        <ClCompile">
<PreprocessorDefinitions>BUILD_YEAR="$(BUILD_YEAR)";BUILD_DATETIME=$(BUILD_DATETIME);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
        </ClCompile>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>


[System.DateTime]::UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds has a couple of issues. It's probably meant to be [System.DateTime]::UnixEpoch.TotalSeconds. Additionally, UnixEpoch returns a DateTime, not a TimeSpan, and TotalSeconds is not a member of the DateTime struct.

It's as intended. It's calling TotalSeconds on the TimeSpan returned by [System.DateTime]::Now.Subtract([System.DateTime]::UnixEpoch)

Interestingly, though, if I alter it slightly I get a different error: The expression "([System.DateTime]::Now.Subtract([System.DateTime]::UnixEpoch)).TotalSeconds" cannot be evaluated.

yeah - I misread the statement.

Also tried converting TotalSeconds to a string, but that doesn't help

<BUILD_DATETIME>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Subtract($([System.DateTime]::UnixEpoch)).TotalSeconds)</BUILD_DATETIME> --  another $() is needed around the [System.DateTime]::UnixEpoch

    <PropertyGroup>  
        <!-- All Builds -->
        <BUILD_YEAR>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy"))</BUILD_YEAR>
        <BUILD_DATETIME>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Subtract($([System.DateTime]::UnixEpoch)).TotalSeconds)</BUILD_DATETIME>
    </PropertyGroup>

The nested property function needs to be contained within its own $().
See Nested property functions in the MSBuild documentation.

Thanks, that helps but I get a different error: error  : Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[System.DateTime]::UnixEpoch". Method 'System.DateTime.UnixEpoch' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(a, b)). Check that all parameters are defined, are of the correct type, and are specified in the right order.

Also tried this, with the same result: $(([System.DateTime]::Now.Subtract($([System.DateTime]::FromFileTime(116444736000000000)))).TotalSeconds)

OK, managed it! $([System.DateTime]::Now.Subtract($([System.DateTime]::FromFileTime(116444736000000000)))).TotalSeconds. Looks like UnixEpoch is unavailable for some reason just as ToUnixTimeMilliseconds is. Thank you for your help

UnixEpoch worked for me. The code that I provided, I tested with MSBuild v16 and v17.

Do you .Net (aka .Net Core) installed? UnixEpoch is supported in .Net Core 2.1 and later. The current LTS is .Net 8. UnixEpoch is not supported in .Net Framework (which is Windows only).

<UnixTimeStamp>$([System.DateTimeOffset]::UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds())</UnixTimeStamp>

